# Matching similar routes in Google Maps. Can it be done?

Tags: java, google-maps

I have encountered a slight problem.
Is there a way to match routes in Google Maps so that as long as the 2 routes moves along the same path, they will be matched. 
For example, Andrew is going from Point A to Point B, and James is going from Point A1 to Point B1. 
Although their destinations are different, but because the route from Point A to Point B passes through Point A1 and B1, Google Maps matches these 2 routes together. 
Can this be done? If so, how?

Answer (score 0):

i am not 100 percent sure about but think about this,

Google keeps driving or walking directions(polylines) as encoded strings. there are some js codes to decode these and you will see this string has many lines start and end point according to a pattern to save string length.

like this

```
"}wjiGtdpcNrAlBJZ"
```

they will be an exact start coordinate and coordinate differences of other points of a direction. 
like these coordinates;

```
-0.00001, 43.64175
-79.38652, 43.64133
-79.38707000000001, 43.641270000000006
-79.38721000000001, 43.641270000000006
```

so if you encode two different direction and turn these points to exact coordinates you can compare them by checking start and end coordinates are same. because "-0.00001, 43.64175" part or another ones will be in the other way's polyline too if they intersects.

i think you can know if a to b and c to d intersects on same street or particular distance.

Comment: http://jeffreysambells.com/posts/2010/05/27/decoding-polylines-from-google-maps-direction-api-with-java/ check this site for a java version of polyline decoder.

Comment: Hi! Has everyone tryed this out?